# How to solve Windows 10 100% disk activity

Tags: windows-10

After upgrading from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 my laptop suffered from slow boot continued by 100% disk activity for up to 30 minutes after the desktop loaded.

I've tried all tips I found on the web without success. I've been asking on the Microsoft forums but only got generic advice that didn't help anything. I also disabled lots of services without success. I've triple checked my harddrive for errors, it's brand new and there are none.

Couple of weeks ago I made a clean install and the issues where gone.

Now it's back. Again I have no real clue what's causing it. These screenshots are made 10 minutes after booting.
[image]
Right now the Resource Monitor shows about 10 pages of svchost activity.
[image]

After some time (5-30 minutes) it just stops and doesn't come back until next boot.

How can I eventually trace and solve these problems?

My laptop is an Acer V3-772 with a GTX750m, 8GB RAM, Core i5-4200m and a regular 500GB harddisk.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 still have issues with it's RAM Management where it compress the memory and then writes it to the disk. I saw reports (and experience) scenarios where at 25%, windows will try to compress the memory to save memory space then writes it to the disk. The fault happens when windows includes it's temporary space in to data to compress causing high CPU usage and hang some disk writes.

The only solution I found is to add more RAM (extra 4GB boosting my RAM to 12GB). Normally it is accompanied with high CPU usage (mine spikes at 80% while some gets 100%)

Comment: What do you expect for a Free OS....  ;-)

Comment: It is not free, you can't get windows 10 for nothing. The only way to can get it is to buy windows 7, 8 (the buggy version), 8.1 or Windows 10. Free to upgrade is not equal to free OS

Comment: Its a Free upgrade any way you stack it.

Comment: The real "free" Linux works much better on that Laptop - boot in 10 seconds, instant standby or shutdown, no issues at all, except the graphics driver support...